# Datagrid not updating

Tags: c#, mysql, datagrid

```
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM `call`", con);
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataset, "call");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset;
        dataGridView1.Update();
```

Here is the above code

It runs fine but there is nothing in the datagrid :(

Any help will be apreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DataGridView will not work when pointed to a DataSet. You have to point it to a DataTable

Change your code to:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables["call"];
```

Comment: wooot love :D (585 characters left)